# Ways to represent UTF-8 in XML messages

Tags: xml, utf-8

Hopefully this is not a dumb question

So, when representing a non ASCII character in UTF-8 encoding in XML I know we can use a decimal or HEX representation

'&#' [0-9]+ ';'  (decimal)

'&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+  ';' (Hex)

To take the following example of an emoji, we can have

Decimal HTML Entity =   ampersand + #128578;

Hexadecimal HTML Entity =   ampersand + #x1f642; (HEX Code Point)

However, another representation of UTF-8 HEX value for this emoji is 
F0 9F 99 82

So, if we were putting F0 9F 99 82 into the XML, does it just go like that OR does it get prefixed and if so how?

When would you use ampersand + #x1f642; vs F0 9F 99 82?

Comment: utf-8 is a specific _encoding_ of unicode, that's not what goes into an entity - those take a codepoint. If your entire _document_ is utf8 encoded then you can reasonably put raw utf8-encoded characters in it.

Comment: If you aren't attempting to hand-write XML with UTF-8 as the document encoding, there is no point in using XML numeric character entity references. Even if you do, a typical XML processor using UTF-8 as an output encoding would righteously undo the way you've written it.

Answer (score 3):

If you write the document encoded in UTF-8, then the raw UTF-8-encoded bytes can be in the file.  Note the declaration of encoding:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<test></test>
```

If you aren't encoded in UTF-8, HTML entities can give the same result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ascii'?>
<test>&#x1f642;&#128578;</test>
```

Comment: would it be something like > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8.  If sending in a JSON response